# What is parse error? how to remove it?

Tags: haskell

In this Script,

```
approximation :: Int -> (String, Int)
approximation x
  | (x<20000) && (19000<=x) && (numDigits<x) = (text1, x-numDigits)
  | (x<20000) && (19000<=x) && (numDigits>x) = (text1, numDigits-x)
  | (x<19800) && (x>=19700) && (numDigits<x) = (text2, x-numDigits)
  | (x<19800) && (x>=19700) && (numDigits>x) = (text2, numDigits-x) 
  | otherwise                                = ("far from no. of Digits", 0)  
      where
        text1 = "at 1000th place of no. of reallyBig, abosolute error="
        text2  = "at 100th place of  no. of reallyBig, nearly Exact, absolute error"
```

I inputted 2 definitions: `text1, text2` for the Function `approximation`. However, the compiler GHCI said there is a `Parse error on input '='` in `text2`. I was confused by the problem.

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't seem to have a parse error. Could you edit in the exact code that gives the error?

Comment: If you are working in GHCi, do not forget to prepend your definitions with `let`: `let approximation x...` — the `parse error on input '='` is the exact error that is shown when you define stuff in GHCi without `let`

Comment: ... and if that's the problem, it's much better to save your definitions in a file like `mycode.hs` and then load it in ghci with the comman `:l mycode.hs` d

Answer (score 3):

You have mixed tabs and spaces for your indentation. This is a bad plan, because your editor and ghc can think about tabs quite differently. I think your editor is displaying tabs as (up to) 4 characters, whereas ghc thinks of tabs as (up to) 8 spaces. I'll write `<-->` for a tab and `.` for a space in your last two lines:

```
<-->....text1 = "at 1000th place of no. of reallyBig, abosolute error="
<--><-->text2  = "at 100th place of  no. of reallyBig, nearly Exact, absolute error"
```

Which is how your editor displays it. If I put ghc's 8 space tabs in, you get

```
<-------->....text1 = "at 1000th place of no. of reallyBig, abosolute error="
<--------><-------->text2  = "at 100th place of  no. of reallyBig, nearly Exact, absolute error"
```

and you get the parse error.

### It's easiest if you stick to spaces. Change your editor's settings.

If you use just spaces, you can't get this problem, because your editor has to show it the way the compiler thinks about it.

My editor lets me specify that when I press tab, it should insert the number of spaces that a tab would show as, so I use that, which is safe for a tabstop of 4. If your editor can do that, use that option. (If not, consider getting a cleverer editor for when you're programming.

My editor also has auto indent and outdent, where the next line copies the whitespace indentation of the previous line - this avoids the problem. Turn this on if your editor supports it, because it saves you effort and you're less likely to get the parse error. (When I then press backspace, my editor deletes back to the previous level of indentation, which is nice.)

Almost all editors can change how they display tabs. If you can't get it to use spaces for tabs, you should change the tabstop to be 8, because that matches ghc, and you're much less likely to get this error, but you're still better off using spaces.